# Grouping together words in a string which have common substrings of some length

Tags: python

I want to display words with common substring in a string.
for example if given string is

```
str = "the games are lame"
```

and the words have to be grouped together on the basis of common substring of length 3, so output should be

```
the 
games, lame 
are
```

since common substring of length 3 is "ame".

I proceeded by converting the string to list say "lista" using split() and made another list say "listb" with all the possible substrings of length 3, like

```
the, gam, gme, ges, ame, aes, mes, are, lam, lme, ame
```

then I checked the "listb" for duplicate items('ame') and on basis of them compared with items in "lista" like so

```
for items in duplicate:
       for item in lista:
           if items in item and not in listc:
               listc.append(item)
```

Now, I have a "listc" with items that have common substring of length 3 but I can't figure out how to group them as needed in output. Also if "str" contains more words with common substring "listc" will also have those common words.
I don't know if I should have proceeded in this way and can't seem to figure out how to group items from "listc" as needed in output.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
str_ = "the games are lame"

# first I get a list of all the words
words = str_.split()
# words >>> ['the', 'games', 'are', 'lame']

groups = []
# This variable will contain the list of words

# For each words
for word in words:
    found = False

    # Get the first words of each groups
    other_words = [x[0] for x in groups if x != word]

    # Loop through the word and get all substring of 3 characters
    for i in range(len(word)):
        substring = word[i:i+3]

        # Eliminates the substring that doesn't have the correct length
        if len(substring) != 3:
            continue

        try:
            # try to find the substring in a group and get the corresponding index of that group
            index = [substring in other_word for other_word in other_words].index(True)
            found = True

            # Add the word in the group
            groups[index].append(word)
        except ValueError:
            continue

    # If we don't find a group for the word, we create a new group with that word in it
    if not found:
        groups.append([word])


# groups >>> [['the'], ['games', 'lame'], ['are']]

# Now print the groups
for group in groups:
    print(", ".join(group))
```

output :

```
the
games, lame
are
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're creating a lot of lists there and this can be quite confusing.

If you want to use a *purely logical approach* without using libraries designed for **sequence matching**, such as **`difflib`**, you can first define a function that compares two strings; then you separate your sentence into a words list and perform a double iteration (nested) through that list comparing all possible pairs.

If the strings match they will be printed on the same line separated by commas otherwise on a new line.

In the following function I've also added a parameter for the length of the substring that you want to match, set to 3 by default to stay in line with your question:

```
# This function compairs two strings and returns them in a tuple if they contain the 
# same substring of len_substring characters.

def string_matcher(string_a, string_b, len_substring = 3):
    for i in range(len(string_a)-len_substring):
        if string_a[i:i+len_substring] in string_b:
            return string_a, string_b
    return None

string = "the games are lame"
words = string.split()

output = ""

# Making a double iteration over the words list and calling string_matcher for each pair.
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    output = output+words[i]
    for j in range(i+1, len(words)):
        try:
            word_a, word_b = string_matcher(words[i], words[j])
            output = output+", "+word_b
        except TypeError:
            pass
    output = output+"\n"

print(output)
```

The program prints out:

```
the
games, lame
are
```